# Concatenate Multiple QSplitter in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qsplitter

I have 3 QWidgets which I want to concatenate. Basically it should look like this:

```
           |           |
           |           |
QWidget 1  | QWidget 2 | QWidget 3
           |           |
           |           |
       QSplitter1  QSplitter2
```

What I tried so far is:

1) Adding each widget to the corresponding QSplitter

```
widget1 = QWidget()
widget2 = QWidget()
widget3 = QWidget()

splitter1 = QSplitter(self)
splitter2 = QSplitter(self)

splitter1.addWidget(widget1)
splitter1.addWidget(widget2)

splitter2.addWidget(widget2)
splitter2.addWidget(widget3)
```

Here I get one moveable splitter, which should be splitter2

2) Adding the complete splitter1 Widget to splitter2 as first argument

```
widget1 = QWidget()
widget2 = QWidget()
widget3 = QWidget()

splitter1 = QSplitter(self)
splitter2 = QSplitter(self)

splitter1.addWidget(widget1)
splitter1.addWidget(widget2)

splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)
splitter2.addWidget(widget3)
```

Here only the first splitter is active.

What is the correct approach doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QSplitter is a *container* widget, and it behaves similarly to a QBoxLayout, adding the possibility of resizing the items. This means that you (normally) only need one splitter, no matter how many widgets you are adding in the same orientation.

What you are referring to as "splitters", are actually the splitter *handles* ([QSplitterHandle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitterhandle.html) classes), so the structure is actually this:

```
QSplitter -------------------------------------+
|               |               |              |
h               H               H              |
a               A               A              |
n               N               N              |
d   QWidget 1   D   QWidget 2   D  QWidget 3   |
l               L               L              |
e               E               E              |
|               |               |              |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

So, that's just as easy as this:

```
widget1 = QWidget()
widget2 = QWidget()
widget3 = QWidget()

splitter = QSplitter(self)
splitter.addWidget(widget1)
splitter.addWidget(widget2)
splitter.addWidget(widget3)
```

Comment: Thank you, also I really like the additional explanation for the difference between what I thought a splitter was, and what it actually is.